# Convert date in Domain class that is created by EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a model using EF6 ,one of my entities as you can see here :

```
public partial class Comment
    {
        public Comment()
        {
            this.Points = new HashSet<Point>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdeaId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string JurorId { get; set; }
        public string CommectDesc { get; set; }
        public string Point { get; set; }

        public virtual Idea Idea { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Point> Points { get; set; }
    }
```

Can i convert **date** column using **get{}** in this class?I mean i need to converted my date ?because i save the date using **datetime.now** but when i want to show the date to user i have to convert it to **persian** date.

Comment: Where do you need to access this date? Convert it to the format you want there, not in your model.

Comment: i need to show the converted date in my view in prsentation layer that i create by mvc

Comment: Then show that code. You can just print the date like `@Model.Date.ToString("your format")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to create new propery and decorate it with [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped] Attribute,
Like this

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }


[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public DateTime PersianDate
    {
        get
        {
                var value  = ConvertToHijri(Date);

                return (value);
        }
    }
```

not you have extra field that not mapped to your database,
when you want to show datetime in hijri format,
you can use PersianDate property instead of Date Property